# How to set date range in SVN for ShowLog

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

"ShowLog" command is displaying only last week logs in TortoiseSVN and not able to select date range to current date due to not showing current week days.

I want to check logs from date on project created to current date.So how to enable to select date ranges.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to click **Show All** or **Next 100** to get older log messages. 
Please, read the documentation:

- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Revision Log Dialog](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html)
- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Getting more log messages](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-3)